# showing users within the tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was following a tutorial on basic php tables to show the users 
http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/

the problem that i have is my platform does not support MySQL so i change it to MySQL

the second problem is that the users i displaying a above the table

this is an image to better description : 
http://store2.up-00.com/2014-02/1391915459381.jpg

and this is the code that i am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');

        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['first_name']; 

                 echo  $id; 
                 echo $fname;


                 }

                   // echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                   // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysqli_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You need to place your `echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";` above (outside) your loop.

Comment: Notice how `echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";` in the tutorial, that it's outside the `while` loop `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))`? Well, do the same. See my first comment. I really don't want to get my "Can opener" for this one.

Comment: thank you so much for respond as you notice i did not change the location of echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>"; it is the same from the tutorial  really sorry if i misunderstand you

Comment: That is most bizarre. I guess I was wrong then. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Where you have `echo "<tr>";` try doing `echo "<tr><td>";` then where you have `echo "</tr>";` try `echo "</td></tr>";`

Comment: i try it it work but every thing went inside the id field  :                  http://store1.up-00.com/2014-02/13919180001.jpg

Comment: Well, it's a start and is better than what you had before.

Comment: Do you only have the 3 columns?

Comment: I also noticed that you have 5 cells on top (with 2 empty on the right), 3 are used for ID, First Name and Last Name, but you are only using 2 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Addendum to Edit #3**

Should you want to add extra cells later on, just follow the same convention.

```
// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $fname = $row['first_name']; 
    $lname = $row['last_name'];

    echo "<tr><td>"; // do not modify
    echo  $id; 
    echo "</td>"; // do not modify
    echo "<td>";
    echo $fname;
    echo "<td>";
    echo $lname;
    // there should not be anything below this
    // besides the echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</td></tr>"; // do not modify
}
```

### Edit 3

I added `$lname = $row['lname'];` for your `Last Name` column and `echo $lname;` and a few other things. So you may need to modify that `$lname = $row['lname'];` to suit yours.

Try this now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');


        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM animals");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        // echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                 echo "<tr>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['name']; 
                 $lname = $row['lname'];

                  echo "<tr><td>";
                 echo  $id; 
                  echo "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td>";
                 echo $fname;
                  echo "<td>";
                 echo $lname;
                  echo "</td></tr>"; 

                 }

                   // echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                   // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysqli_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
         echo "</td></tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### EDIT 2

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');

        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        // echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                 echo "<tr>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['first_name']; 

                 echo "<td>";
                 echo  $id; 
                 echo "</td>";
                 echo "<td>";
                 echo $fname;
                 echo "</td>"; 

                 }

                   // echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                   // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysqli_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
         echo "</tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### EDIT 1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');

        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        // echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                 echo "<tr>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['first_name']; 

                 echo "<td>";
                 echo  $id; 
                 echo $fname;
                 echo "</td>"; 

                 }

                   // echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                   // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysqli_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
         echo "</tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Original answer

Try the full code below.

I added a `<td>` in `echo "<tr>";` and `</td>` in `echo "</tr>";`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW-PAGINATED.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
        This is a modified version of view.php that includes pagination
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('config.php');

        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 1;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $total_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='admin_user_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr><td>";

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $fname = $row['first_name']; 

                 echo  $id; 
                 echo $fname;

                 }

                   // echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                   // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysqli_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</td></tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination

?>
<p><a href="admin/admin_user_add.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try it it is still the same every thing on id     will i have more than 3 but i will add them after figured this one out really appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. Reload my answer under `Edit 1` @user3029453 - Hoping it will work. You may need to view your source to see how the HTML is laid out to troubleshoot it better.

Comment: Reload it again, I think I might have made a slight error. @user3029453

Comment: it is work but it is not separate users form id                                       http://store2.up-00.com/2014-02/139191918031.jpg

Comment: I think I fixed it. Reload for `Edit 2` @user3029453

Comment: If `Edit 2` doesn't work, give me a few minutes. Let me know. @user3029453 These are very tricky.

Comment: take your time really appreciate your help

Comment: Ok, I think I have it now. Reload and look at `Edit 3` @user3029453

Comment: it is working now for the tables but still have an issue with the pages because it sould only display 1 name per page because i am trying to do view with paginated as on the toturial                 : http://store2.up-00.com/2014-02/1391920754996.jpg                                                        thank you so much really apprecite your help

Comment: The pagination part I won't be able to help with. I've never done pagination before. @user3029453

Comment: thank you thank you @Fred -ii-  really do not know how to thank you really appreciate your help    and i hope some one can help me with the pagination

Comment: You're welcome. If you want, you can click on the `White checkmark` till it turns `Green`. That will be accepting my answer and close the question. You could then use my last Edit in a new question to ask for help on the pagination part. You will have my blessing :) @user3029453